# How can I change the xlim on a forest plot produced by meta package

Tags: r, axis, meta, r-forestplot

I am using the meta package to run a meta-analysis and produce forest plots. I have several different datasets and each is producing a forest plot with different scales on the x-axis. I am trying to edit the code so that the xlim can be changed, but nothing changes.

e.g.

```
forest(m1)
```

Produced a plot with x axis in the range -0.7 - 0.7

I would like to limit the x axis to -0.4 - 0.4

I've tried:

```
forest(m1, xlim=c(-0.4,0.4))
```

But nothing changes

I have also tried:

```
fores(m1, xlim=c(-0.4,0.4), asp=NA)
```

Again, nothing changes. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using `metamean` before `forest` ? Could you try this code and let me know? `m1 <- metamean(rep(100, 3), 1:3, rep(1, 3))` and
`forest(m1, xlim=c(0,4))` ? It works on my R.